# Can MIPS addu be used in 2's complement arithmetic?

Tags: mips

In Mips, Addu does not produce an exception on overflow. So can it still be used for 2's complement arithmetic?

I think the answer is no. That's because if an overflow occurs, it means that the result exceeds the available hardware space. So there is a need to throw an exception.

What do you think?

Comment: What is wrong with it *not* producing an exception? Would it produce an exception in IA-32/x86? (I'm not saying it can be used as such, but do not believe the current argument is valid.)

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between adding unsigned values and signed (2's complement) values. Therefore, you can use both `add` and `addu` for signed values.

The fact that `addu` does not raise an exception in case of overflow is a completely different matter. Some other architectures never do that anyway. Whether or not you need an exception when overflow occurs is not really dependent on whether you use signed or unsigned arithmetic. You can as well ask if `addu` can be used in unsigned arithmetic since there is a risk of unnoticed overflows.